# How do I create multiple activity feeds using the same appid and key?

Tags: getstream-io

We allow our creators to create their own site, so how do we get one feed per site?
How do we create multiple react activity feeds using one single getsteam app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to adopt a naming convention to your feed and include some namespacing.

For instance, you could make feed IDs include the name or the ID of the application:

ie. `timeline:${app.id}-${user.id}` would be the timeline feed ID for app's user.